# unable to validate the XML with XSD schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

I am new to XML validation.

My XSD is

```
<xsd:complexType name="RootForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="TRADE" type="RecordForm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:attribute name="ASOF_DATE" use="required">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="CREATE_DATE" use="required">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="RECORDS" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The code that i an running is:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    spf.setValidating(true);
    InputSource i = new InputSource("X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/trades.xml");
    InputSource i1 = new InputSource("X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd");
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    saxParser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",  "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    saxParser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", i1);
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
   // xmlReader.setContentHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());

    try {
        xmlReader.parse(i);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the below exception:

```
src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'RootForm'. It was detected that 'RootForm' is in namespace 'http://www.w3schools.com', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'RootForm' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd'.
   Public ID: null
   System ID: file:///X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd
   Line number: 6
   Column number: 52
   Message: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'RootForm'. It was detected that 'RootForm' is in namespace 'http://www.w3schools.com', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'RootForm' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///X:/workspace/XMLValidation/src/xml/transactions.xsd'.
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'TRANSACTIONS'.
```

Can any one please help me what i m doing wrong in the xsd file

Thanks
Avnish

Comment: components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document. Please provide show your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the XML file you are parsing as well?
Also the "RecordForm" type that the Trade element takes is not defined in the schema.
Try including that and see.
The namespace that you are using should be imported to distinguish the elements in the XML.

Comment: `<TRANSACTIONS xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./transactions.xsd" ASOF_DATE="6/10/2011" CREATE_DATE="6/10/2011" RECORDS="1769"> <TRADE> <ACCRUAL_DT>09/22/2012</ACCRUAL_DT> <COUNTERPARTY_CODE>US</COUNTERPARTY_CODE> <CUSIP>BRS87R7N9</CUSIP> <DESC_INSTMT>CFD COOKSON GROUP PLC</DESC_INSTMT> <DESK></DESK> <TRADE> <TRANSACTIONS>`

Comment: You have not specified the TRANSACTIONS element in the schema. It should be specified that it uses the RoboForm type.

Comment: i specified the TRANSACTIONS element in the xsd file but still the same exception                                                                <xsd:element name="TRANSACTIONS" type="RootForm"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct ans from my side for yours which will surely help you out:

Firstly the xml which you had was not of proper syntax which i have corrected in here:

```
<TRANSACTIONS xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./transactions.xsd" ASOF_DATE="6/10/2011"  CREATE_DATE="6/10/2011" RECORDS="1769"> 
<TRADE> 
<ACCRUAL_DT>
09/22/2012
</ACCRUAL_DT> 
<COUNTERPARTY_CODE>
US
</COUNTERPARTY_CODE> 
<CUSIP>
BRS87R7N9
</CUSIP> 
<DESC_INSTMT>
CFD COOKSON GROUP PLC
</DESC_INSTMT> 
<DESK/>
</TRADE> 
</TRANSACTIONS>
```

Now simple go to the site: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

Enter the XML mentioned above and click Generate XSD Schema. So now the schema would be generated and thereafter save it in your local disk and then run the code below to check and verify it!

```
package your_package name;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLValidator
{

public void validate() {
    File xmlFile = new File(Provide the xml file location (disk) in double quotes);
    File xsdFile = new File(Provide the xml file location (disk) in double quotes);
    boolean retStat = this.validateSchema(xmlFile, xsdFile);
    if(retStat){    
        System.out.println("Validated");
    }       
    else
        System.out.println("Not Valid");
}

private boolean validateSchema(File xml, File xsd){
    Schema schema = null;
    try{
        schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xsd);
    }catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }catch(Exception fnEx){
        fnEx.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    if(null != schema){
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

        try {
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
            return true;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    XMLValidator newObj=new XMLValidator();
    newObj.validate();
}
```

}

And therby by solved!!

Comment: Thanks you so much ... code is running perfectly now with new xsd file.I will look into my XSD and find out what went wrong and will post on the forum .My need was to reuse the complex types.But auto generated xsd is serving the purpose

Answer (score 0):

The namespace that you are using should be imported to distinguish the elements in the XML.

Here is the XSD to reuse the ComplexTypes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="TRANSACTIONS" type="RootForm" />
  <xsd:complexType name="RootForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="TRADE" type="RecordForm" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="ASOF_DATE" type="xsd:dateTime" />
    <xsd:attribute name="CREATE_DATE" type="xsd:dateTime" />
    <xsd:attribute name="RECORDS" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="RecordForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ACCRUAL_DT" type="xsd:dateTime" />
      <xsd:element name="COUNTERPARTY_CODE" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="CUSIP" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="DESC_INSTMT" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="DESK" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```